why I encounter this error "No provider for _TemplateRef found"
Why do I encounter this error "No provider for _TemplateRef found" when I add this directive to the App.
export class LoaderDirective implements OnChanges {

  @Input()
  hidden : boolean | null = false;

  private template = inject(TemplateRef<any>);
  private viewContainerRef = inject(ViewContainerRef);

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if(changes["hidden"].currentValue){
      this.viewContainerRef.clear();
    } else {
      this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.template);
    }
  }
}


